# add rows and cols programmatically in existing table without migration -laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, view, rows, laravel-blade

Is there any way to add rows and columns in the existing blade table. Already populate the data using 
foreach loop based on questionlables and contacts. I need to calculate the Average, Min, and Max for the score column in the table.Contacts and questionlabels varies based on the survey selected.
any help is appreciated

```
    @php
     $FIXED_COLUMN_COUNT =5;
     $columnCount = $FIXED_COLUMN_COUNT + count($questionLabels);
     $rowCount = count($contacts) + 3;
    @endphp
   <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
         <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                     <th>StartDate</th>
                    <th>EndDate</th>
                    <th>Score</th>
                    @foreach($questionLabels as $questionLabel)
                      <th>{{ $questionLabel}}</th>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($contacts as $contact)
                 <tr><td></td></tr>
                 .
                 .
                 .
                 ..
                 .@foreach(answers as answer)
                 <tr><td></td></tr>
                 .
                 .
                 .
                 ..
                 @endforeach

                 Here i need max, min and average inside the table

                 </tbody>
                </table>
        </div
```

I want the output like this. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvzHU.png)

Answer (score 0):

like this situation I used jQuery for that you must import [jQuery.js](https://jquery.com/) and try this

```
<script>
 $('#tableId tr:last').after('<tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr>');
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
 $('#tableId > tbody:last-child').append('<tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr>');
</script>
```

Comment: I need a full row to add at the end (row and columns will change based on the number of questions and contacts).  how many tr and do td need to add? i left space at the end of the row

Comment: also, I use datatable.js ( https://datatables.net/) for that. it has some function get values from the column and calculate like get sum column (https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/sum() ) . so try it too